# No Errors but still not drawing anything

Tags: conky

[This Conky Config](https://www.deviantart.com/speedracker/art/Phone-Spotify-Conky-552901328) that I like a lot had a couple of issues when I tried to run it :

1. **Old Syntax:** downloaded Conky converter and changed some variable names by hand as well which fixed it
2. **Missing some endif:** I managed to find where it is, put it in there and fixed

Now Conky doesn't complain about anything but I still don't see it rendering anything, any help with figuring out what is the issue would be much appreciated.

**The new config after the 2 steps mentioned above:**

```js
conky.config = {
-- By Jesse_Avalos , See me on Eye Candy Linux_  on Google +
 background = true,
 use_xft = true,
 font = 'Roboto:size=9',
 xftalpha = 0.8,
 update_interval = 1,
 total_run_times = 0,
 own_window = true,
 own_window_type = 'dock',
 own_window_transparent = true,
 own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
 double_buffer = true,
 draw_shades = false,
 draw_outline = false,
 draw_borders = false,
 draw_graph_borders = false,
 stippled_borders = 0,
 border_inner_margin = 5,
 border_width = 1,
 default_color = '#000000',
 default_shade_color = '#000000',
 default_outline_color = '#000000',
 minimum_width = 800, minimum_height = 800,
 maximum_width = 800,
 gap_x = 1060,
 gap_y = 70,
 alignment = 'top_right',
 no_buffers = true,
 uppercase = false,
 cpu_avg_samples = 2,
 net_avg_samples = 2,
 short_units = true,
 text_buffer_size = 2048,
 use_spacer = 'none',
 override_utf8_locale = true,
--lua_load rings-v1.2.1.lua
 lua_draw_hook_pre = 'ring_stats',

--lua_load lilas_rings.lua
 lua_draw_hook_post = 'main',

-- Text settings #
 use_xft = true,
 xftalpha = 0,
 font = 'TheNautiGal:bold:size=10',
 override_utf8_locale = true,
--lua_load time.lua

-- Color scheme #
 default_color = 'white',
 color1 = '#212021',
 color2 = '#B5B5B5',--E8E1E6
 color3 = '#FFFFFF',

 own_window_argb_value = 0,
 own_window_argb_visual = true,
 own_window_colour = '#000000',
};

conky.text = [[
${offset 110}${color2}${font Aliquam:size=74}${time %I}${color3}
${offset 110}${voffset -20}${font Aliquam:bold:size=74}${time %M}${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:size=12}${color2}
${offset 88}${voffset 10}${time %p - %A %B, %d}${font Aliquam:bold:size=65}${color3}
${image line.png -p 65,230 -s 2x330}
${offset 87}${voffset -225}${font Aliquam:bold:size=18}--- Weather ---

# --- Weather --- #
###################
\
# --- WOEID (Location id) --- #
${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1095209&u=c" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}\
\
# --- Location name (city and country) --- #
############################################
\
${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:slsize=15}${offset 80}${voffset -15}${execi 300 grep "yweather:location" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "city=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"} , ${execi 300 grep "yweather:location" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "country=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}


# --- Textual condition (e.g. Partly cloudy) --- #
##################################################
\
${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:slsize=15}${offset 80}${voffset -25}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "text=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}  

${offset 80}${voffset -5}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}°${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:size=10} celsius

${offset 87}${voffset }${font Aliquam:bold:size=18}---- Spotify ----

${if_running spotify}${voffset -2}${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:slsize=15}
${voffset -35}${goto 80}Title : ${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:slsize=15}
${goto 80}${voffset 2}${color2}${execi 3 dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' string:'Metadata'|egrep -A 1 "title"|egrep -v "title"|cut -b 44-|cut -d '"' -f 1|egrep -v ^$ }${color4}${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:slsize=15}
${goto 80}${voffset 2}Artist : ${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:slsize=15}

${goto 80}${voffset -20}${color2}${execi 3 dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' string:'Metadata'|egrep -A 2 "artist"|egrep -v "artist"|egrep -v "array"|cut -b 27-|cut -d '"' -f 1|egrep -v ^$ }${color4}${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:slsize=15}
${goto 80}Album : ${font Aliquam::UltraLight:bold:slsize=15}

${goto 80}${voffset -18}${color2}${execi 3 dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' string:'Metadata'|egrep -A 1 "album"|egrep -v "album"|cut -b 44-|cut -d '"' -f 1|egrep -v ^$ }${color}${endif}
]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you run conky with your config on the command line in a terminal. If conky is encountering any errors in the config, something should be displayed in the terminal that may give a hint as to what's causing the issue.